# Some rewrite rules for actions

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Now i want to execute some action by a $_GET parameter like this:

```
domain.de/admin.html?delete-forum=10
```

But if i dump $_GET it only returns the page parameter.
In the result i want a link like this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/delete-forum-([^-]*)\.html$ /admin.html?delete-forum=$1 [L]
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you want to append your query string. i.e. your parameter for the index query should look like: `[L,QSA]`. maybe this is what you are searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've added `[L,QSA]` to append the query string